# Multiple directive references bound to document event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive which will allow me to bind keyboard actions to elements in page.
This is the directive

```
angular.module('app').directive('keyboardAction', keyboardAction);
function keyboardAction() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            document.onkeydown = function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == attrs.keyboardAction) {
                    element.click();
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

I have two elements in the DOM that I would like to apply this directive on. One will be the left arrow link and the other is the right:

```
<a href="left-href..." keyboard-action="37" class="arrow left">Left</a>
<a href="right-href..." keyboard-action="39" class="arrow right">Right</a>
```

The problem: Only the last directive reference in the DOM works (the one on the right arrow). It seems that the last directive reference in the DOM overrides the previous document.onkeydown handler.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.addEventListener()`. Directly assigning the event to a property is old hat:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == attrs.keyboardAction) {
        element.click();
    }
});
```